# How to find the cause for an appstore review rejection when it comes to user privacy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

We've just received a binary rejection from the appstore specifying that

> your app uses algorithmically converted device and usage data to
> create a unique identifier in order to track the user. The device
> information collected by your app may include some of the following:
> attributesOfItemAtPath:error:, NSLocaleLanguageCode, NSHomeDirectory,
> NSLocaleCurrencyCode, and getifaddrs.

we're of course using a lot of dependencies, but from a first scan we're unable to identify such algorithm... anyone dealt with this before? any suggestions to find the problematic code / lib?

Comment: Maybe try to search the whole project for the  attributesOfItemAtPath, NSLocaleLanguageCode, NSHomeDirectory, NSLocaleCurrencyCode etc.

Comment: You already have your answer - "... using a lot of dependancies....". Maybe you could (at least?) list them here? Some may be well-known by now, and someone might point them out.

Comment: They also check your ads libraries that you used. Or any other third party libraries. That's usually the root of the problem for rejection. But, it can be PITA dealing with rejection issues. Sometimes it is NOT as what it seems. I had multiple rejections before that I thought was related to a thing, but actually it is another thing. Which caused my app be rejected over and over. Painful process.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the problematic SDK was Adjust.
but still the problem remains no clear way to analyze such feedback from apple

see: https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnkoetsier/2021/04/01/apple-rejecting-apps-with-fingerprinting-enabled-as-ios-14-privacy-enforcement-starts/